# Sending a POST request to my RESTful API(Python-Flask), but receiving a GET request

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, zapier, hasura

I'm trying to send a trigger to a Zapier webhook in the form of a POST request containing JSON. It works fine if I just send the POST request through a local python script.

What I want to do is create a RESTful API which makes the trigger to the Zapier webhook when the create-row-in-gs endpoint is called.

As you can see, I'm sending a POST request API call to the Hasura cluster. But instead of getting the response as '200 OK SUCCESS', I'm getting a '200 OK failure' which means that the request is being treated as a GET request instead of a POST request.

**test.py**

```
#Python 3 Script to send a POST request containing JSON

import json
import requests

api_url = 'http://app.catercorner16.hasura-app.io/create-row-in-gs'
create_row_data = {'id': '1235','name':'Joel','created-on':'27/01/2018','modified-on':'27/01/2018','desc':'This is Joel!!'}
r = requests.post(url=api_url, data=create_row_data)
print(r.status_code, r.reason, r.text)
```

**server.py (Running on Hasura cluster)**

```
from src import app
from flask import jsonify,request,make_response,url_for,redirect
from json import dumps
from requests import post

url = 'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/xxxxx/yyyyy/'

@app.route('/create-row-in-gs', methods=['GET','POST'])
def create_row_in_gs():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return make_response('failure')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        t_id = request.json['id']
        t_name = request.json['name']
        created_on = request.json['created_on']
        modified_on = request.json['modified_on']
        desc = request.json['desc']

        create_row_data = {'id': str(t_id),'name':str(t_name),'created-on':str(created_on),'modified-on':str(modified_on),'desc':str(desc)}

        response = requests.post(
            url, data=json.dumps(create_row_data),
            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        )
        return response
```

Have been struggling with this for weeks. What am I doing wrong? Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but if your request is a failure you shouldn't return 200.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Okay! Will make note of that.

Comment: My guess: you are getting a redirect.Try the `requests.post` with `allow_redirects=False`

Comment: @VPfB Yeah, I did that now, and now it reads '301 Moved Permanently'. Expected?

Comment: @JoelKingsley As I said, I was only guessing from symptoms, that there might by a post/redirect/get pattern hidden somewhere.

Comment: @JoelKingsley Did you try using the https URL instead of the http one? I visited the URL that you linked to in your test.py file, and it's an https URL now. Maybe try that and run `test.py`?

Comment: @iamnat Wow! Just had to use https instead of http. Works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using the right protocol. `http` or `https`.

If you use `http` and see a redirect, the redirect `Location` header will have the correct URL usually.

Answer (score 13):

Ok, I checked you script locally and found two issues. Both are in your client script.

1) `r = requests.post(url=api_url, data=create_row_data)` should be `r = requests.post(url=api_url, json=create_row_data)`

2) You look for `created_on` and `modified_on` in your Flask app, but you send `created-on` and `modified-on`.

Working local code below:

Client:

```
import json
import requests

api_url = 'http://localhost:5000/create-row-in-gs'
create_row_data = {'id': '1235','name':'Joel','created_on':'27/01/2018','modified_on':'27/01/2018','desc':'This is Joel!!'}
print(create_row_data)
r = requests.post(url=api_url, json=create_row_data)
print(r.status_code, r.reason, r.text)
```

Server:

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify,request,make_response,url_for,redirect
import requests, json

app = Flask(__name__)

url = 'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/xxxxx/yyyyy/'

@app.route('/create-row-in-gs', methods=['GET','POST'])
def create_row_in_gs():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return make_response('failure')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        t_id = request.json['id']
        t_name = request.json['name']
        created_on = request.json['created_on']
        modified_on = request.json['modified_on']
        desc = request.json['desc']

        create_row_data = {'id': str(t_id),'name':str(t_name),'created-on':str(created_on),'modified-on':str(modified_on),'desc':str(desc)}

        response = requests.post(
            url, data=json.dumps(create_row_data),
            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        )
        return response.content

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost',debug=False, use_reloader=True)
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, but some of the imports threw errors as well

Comment: Found this useful to get rid of those 2 issues. But the main issue still exists. Might be a cluster service-specific problem, as it works for me locally too.